Chrome hangs when hitting ESCape in a fullScreen video window
Chrome is able to show fullscreen videos but it can not reset the video standard mode. The audio still plays but chrome has altogether frozen: all other chrome windows are also frozen and no new windows may be opened.
No other applications are affected and Activity Monitor does not report Chrome as unresponsive. But I have to End task on it at that point.
This behavior applies to any website in chrome that I have tried including youtube, google, netflix, espn, nytimes etc.
I am on Sonoma 14.4 with all latest patches in place and have the latest Chrome :
Chrome is up to date
Version 125.0.6422.142 (Official Build) (x86_64)


Can you test if the problem still persists if you login as another user?
